# Undefined local variable from an external file ("Why's Poignant Guide to Ruby")

Tags: ruby

I have been using [Why's Poignant Guide to Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/book/chapter-4.html) and am stuck on a particular example. The code asks to create two files, with one being linked to the other using `require 'wordlist'` (which did not originally work, but after getting an error and searching around I found adding `./` *before* `wordlist` as a solution).

After retyping a couple of times, and then just copying-pasting, the `Enter your idea:` prompt appears, but after that I get an error saying:

```
test.rb:6:in '<main>': undefined local variable or method 'code_words' for main:Object     (NameError)
```

What I get from this is that the main file is still not recognizing the variable declared in `wordlist.rb`? Thanks, I'm really new to this!

**wordlist.rb:**

```
code_words = {
  'starmonkeys' => 'Phil and Pete, those prickly chancellors of the New Reich',
  'catapult' => 'chucky go-go', 
  'firebomb' => 'Heat-Assisted Living',
  'Nigeria' => "Ny and Jerry's Dry Cleaning (with Donuts)",
  'Put the kabosh on' => 'Put the cable box on'
}
```

**test.rb:**

```
require './wordlist'

print "Enter your new idea: " 
idea = gets
code_words.each do |real, code| 
idea.gsub!( real, code )
end

print "File encoded.  Please enter a name for this idea: " 
idea_name = gets.strip
File::open( "idea-" + idea_name + ".txt", "w" ) do |f|
  f << idea
end
```

Comment: what is in the `test.rb` file??

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I just edited that in to my original post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A local variable cannot be shared among different files. `code_words` defined in `wordlist.rb` is not accessible from `test.rb`. You either need to put them in a single file, or use a constant or a different kind of a variable (instance, class, or global) with appropriate scope.

Comment: Thanks! Weird that they wouldn't mention this in the tutorial though

Answer (score 0):

`code_words` is a local variable. Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in, that's why they are called *local* variables. `code_words` is defined in the scope of the `wordlist.rb` script. It is *not* defined anywhere else.